# What's the sense behind that lemma?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Please if someone can help and can take 3 minutes I would be so so unbelievably happy because it is really important to me... Thank you :)

We assume we have a $m$-th root of unity $\zeta_m=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$.

Also obviously for $i=0,\ldots,m-1$ we have in total $m$ different $m$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, namely:

$$\zeta_m^k=e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{m}}, k \in \{0\ldots,m-1\}.$$

Also we obviously have from the geometric sum formula $\zeta_m^{m-1}=e^{\frac{2\pi i (m-1)}{m}}= \sum \limits_{k=0}^{m-2} -\zeta_m^k$ because from the geometric sum formula we get $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m-1} \zeta_m^k=0$. So for this reason we can transfer any sum like $x_0 \zeta_m^0+ \ldots+ x_{m-1} \zeta_{m}^{m-1}$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ into a sum like $y_0 \zeta_m^0+ \ldots+ y_{m-2} \zeta_{m}^{m-2}$ with $y_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For this reason we can write any sum like this as a vector of dimension $1\times (m-1)$. Now we say two sums like that are congruent modulo $n$ if all the entries of the vector are congruent modulo $n$;

So now we can finally go to that lemma I don't understand:

The lemma says:

> If $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $n \nmid m$ and assume $\zeta_m^j \equiv \zeta_m^k \pmod{n}$. Then we already get according to the lemma $\zeta_m^j = \zeta_m^k$.

What I don't understand: What is the sense of the lemma? Of course if I take $m=2$, then I could find with $n=2$ or $n=1$ an example where the elements are congruent but still not the same; Also if I take $m$ larger than $2$ and $n=1$;

But can anyone give me an example where $n \mid m$ and then the saying of the lemma would not be correct? (considering $m>2$ and $n$ is not $1$)
Because the lemma seems to be so useless that I am afraid I didn't understand it properly..

Thank you again so much for helping.. :)

Comment: An example why I consider the lemma not true for example for n=2 and m=2; For example is $\zeta_2^1 =-\zeta_2^0$ accodrding to the geometric sum formula so for this reason the vector representation for $\zeta_2^0$ is $(1)$ and for $\zeta_2^1$ it's $(-1)$ and because they are kongruent to $n=2$ but not the same the lemma would fail here; But anyone has some example with bigger numbers?

Comment: I just can't see any failure of the lemma if $n \mid m$ if these numbers are a little bigger

Comment: The sense of a lemma would typically be its application in proofs of more interesting theorems. Isn't there any such application in a proof nearby in the text where you found this lemma?

Comment: It is indeed part of a bigger theorem... However I'm so unsure if I actually understood the lemma in the right way, that's why I'm asking... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest case: Let $m=4$, $n=2$. Then $\zeta_m=i$ and $i\equiv -i=i^3\pmod 2$, but of course $i\ne -i$.
More generally, if $m=2k$ and $n=2$ then $\zeta_m^k=-1$ and hence $\zeta_m^k\equiv \zeta_m^0\pmod n$.